# Delphi XE5: How to stop scrolling in a TButtonGroup

Tags: delphi

I have a TbuttonGroup set to alClient inside a TCategoryPanel that I can't stop from scrolling with the mouse wheel. When the focus is set to the button group even though all the items are already visible, and the size is set to hold everything + 2 pixels, it will move the contents of the button group up and hide the first item and create a blank space at the bottom. I've not found anything related to this behaviour in my own research, so could use a suggestion if anyone has it!

Images:

Before Scrolling

[image: Before Scrolling]

After Scrolling 1

[image: After Scrolling 1]

After Scrolling 2

[image: After Scrolling 2]

The only way I have found so far to stop it is to set it 1 full button height(24px) taller. However, this isn't really acceptable as a solution to  the issue when it comes a GUI.

Copy of the DFM:

```
object MainF: TMainF
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'MainF'
  ClientHeight = 550
  ClientWidth = 785
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnPaint = FormPaint
  OnResize = FormResize
  DesignSize = (
    785
    550)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 200
    Top = 45
    Width = 585
    Height = 505
    Align = alClient
    BevelInner = bvNone
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Color = clWindow
    ParentColor = False
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = FlowPanel1Click
    object FlowPanel1: TFlowPanel
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 585
      Height = 105
      Align = alTop
      AutoSize = True
      BevelOuter = bvNone
      Color = clWindow
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = FlowPanel1Click
    end
  end
  object CategoryPanelGroup1: TCategoryPanelGroup
    Left = 0
    Top = 45
    Height = 505
    VertScrollBar.Tracking = True
    HeaderFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    HeaderFont.Color = clWindowText
    HeaderFont.Height = -11
    HeaderFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    HeaderFont.Style = []
    TabOrder = 1
    object CategoryPanel2: TCategoryPanel
      Top = 220
      Height = 100
      Caption = 'Hail'
      TabOrder = 0
      object ButtonGroup2: TButtonGroup
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 196
        Height = 74
        Align = alClient
        BorderStyle = bsNone
        ButtonOptions = [gboFullSize, gboShowCaptions]
        Items = <
          item
            Caption = 'Extended Crop Report'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Total Crop Summary Report'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Crop Summary Report'
          end>
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end
    object CategoryPanel1: TCategoryPanel
      Top = 0
      Height = 220
      Caption = 'Assessment'
      TabOrder = 1
      object ButtonGroup1: TButtonGroup
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 196
        Height = 194
        Align = alClient
        BorderStyle = bsNone
        ButtonOptions = [gboFullSize, gboShowCaptions]
        Items = <
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By Property(Detailed)'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By Property'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment Summary 1 Page'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By PPC'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By LPC'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By Authority For LPC'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Property By Assessment Number'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'Assessment By Authority For PPC'
          end>
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 785
    Height = 45
    Align = alTop
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    ParentColor = True
    TabOrder = 2
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 10
      Top = 0
      Width = 349
      Height = 43
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Reports for redacted'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -24
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      Layout = tlCenter
    end
  end
  object WaitPanel: TPanel
    Left = 228
    Top = 167
    Width = 505
    Height = 100
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    Caption = 'A report is open. Please wait...'
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 368
    Top = 152
    object mnuFile1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'File'
      object mnuExit1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Exit'
      end
    end
    object Settings1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Settings'
      object mnuReports1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Reports'
        OnClick = mnuReports1Click
      end
      object mnuChangeCommon1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Change Common Reports'
        OnClick = mnuChangeCommon1Click
      end
    end
    object mnuHelp1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Help'
      object mnuAbout1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'About'
        OnClick = mnuAbout1Click
      end
    end
  end
  object ReportListDB: TABSDatabase
    Connected = True
    CurrentVersion = '7.30 '
    DatabaseFileName = ''
    DatabaseName = 'RptName'
    Exclusive = False
    MaxConnections = 500
    MultiUser = False
    SessionName = 'Default'
    Left = 336
    Top = 261
  end
  object ReportList: TABSTable
    CurrentVersion = '7.30 '
    DatabaseName = 'RptName'
    InMemory = False
    ReadOnly = False
    StoreDefs = True
    IndexDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'IDKey'
        Fields = 'ID'
        Options = [ixPrimary]
      end>
    IndexName = 'IDKey'
    FieldDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'ID'
        DataType = ftAutoInc
      end
      item
        Name = 'ReportFileName'
        DataType = ftString
        Size = 100
      end
      item
        Name = 'ReportTitle'
        DataType = ftString
        Size = 100
      end
      item
        Name = 'ReportClass'
        DataType = ftString
        Size = 20
      end
      item
        Name = 'CommonReports'
        DataType = ftInteger
      end>
    TableName = 'ReportList'
    Exclusive = False
    Left = 408
    Top = 261
    object ReportListCommonReports: TIntegerField
      DisplayWidth = 10
      FieldName = 'CommonReports'
    end
    object ReportListReportTitle: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 30
      FieldName = 'ReportTitle'
      Size = 100
    end
    object ReportListReportClass: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 10
      FieldName = 'ReportClass'
    end
    object ReportListReportFileName: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 45
      FieldName = 'ReportFileName'
      Visible = False
      Size = 100
    end
    object ReportListID: TAutoIncField
      DisplayWidth = 2
      FieldName = 'ID'
      Visible = False
    end
  end
  object ReportOrderQRY: TABSQuery
    CurrentVersion = '7.30 '
    DatabaseName = 'RptName'
    InMemory = False
    ReadOnly = True
    SQL.Strings = (
      'SELECT ID, CommonReports, ReportTitle'
      'FROM ReportList'
      'WHERE CommonReports > 0'
      'ORDER BY CommonReports')
    Left = 480
    Top = 261
    object ReportOrderQRYID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'ID'
    end
    object ReportOrderQRYCommonReports: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'CommonReports'
    end
    object ReportOrderQRYReportTitle: TStringField
      FieldName = 'ReportTitle'
      Size = 100
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICS, the problem is that the total visible rows in a button group is calculated before the button group is resized to fit in the client area of its parent. That happens in `TButtonGroup.Resize` procedure.

One solution is to force a resize after the window has assumed its final size.

```
ButtonGroup1.Height := ButtonGroup1.Height + 1;
```

Although this works, e.g., in a button click, I couldn't find a good place to call it at form creation. Doing it while handling a posted user message is probably still early (not really sure about the reason why it doesn't work).

Another solution can be to attach a handler for the `OnMouseWheelDown` event to prevent further processing.

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonGroup1MouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if ButtonGroup1.ClientHeight >= ButtonGroup1.Items.Count * ButtonGroup1.ButtonHeight then
    Handled := True;
end;
```

.. though the above is still required to hide the scrollbar.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ButtonGroup1.Align = alClient then
    ButtonGroup1.Height := ButtonGroup1.Height + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for finding that. I wouldn't have clued into that as I do some resizing of the Category Panels on FormCreate().


I wonder, is this similar behaviour to CategoryPanelGroup.VertScollBar.Position. If you set it to 0 on form create, after you have added your panels, the position will be 0, but the render will paint it at the lower most limit.

Comment: Yeah, really interesting. I'm really not sure why resizing at form creation hides the scrollbar but does not prevent scrolling.